# Is $\operatorname{Quot}(R)/R$ an injective $R$-Module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, injective-module

Let $R$ be an integral domain. Is the $R$-Module $\DeclareMathOperator{\Quot}{Quot}\Quot(R)/R$ injective? ($\Quot R$ denotes the fraction field of $R$.)

By Baer's criterion it is sufficient to show that for any ideal $J \trianglelefteq R$, all $R$-linear maps $J \to \Quot(R)$ are of the form $a \mapsto c a$ for some $c \in R$.
The statement is true if $R$ is a PID because $\Quot(R)/R$ is a divisible $R$-Module.

Comment: The standard counterexample you'll find in the literature is $\mathbb{Q}[X] / \mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Comment: @ParthivBasu I guess you mean $\mathbb{Q}(X) / \mathbb{Z}[X]$?

Comment: Yes. Also, I think it's helpful to know the following characterization. For a ring $R$, the following are equivalent: $R$ is left hereditary $\leftrightarrow$ every submodule of a projective module is projective $\leftrightarrow$ every quotient of an injective module is injective. Dedekind rings (like PIDs) are examples of heriditary rings. Also, being left heriditary is equivalent to saying that the left global dimension is less than or equal 1.